# Unzipping a zip file creating from windows zip (send to -> zip)

Tags: python, windows, compression, zip

I am getting an error `NotImplementedError: That compression method is not supported` when using `ZipFile` to unpack a zip file. The zip file was creating using the normal Windows zip creator.

I am using the latest version of zip file. Shouldn't it be able to handle a normal windows compression?

Comment: What's "the normal Windows zip creator"?

Comment: When you right click on a folder and press "send to" and then "compressed (zipped) folder"

Comment: The `ZipFile` class only supports the compression methods specified in its [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile-objects) and (apparently) whatever method Windows is using is not one of them — or you're not using it properly (but we can't tell because you haven't posted any code in your question).

Comment: Can you provide an example zip file that gives this error? Are you transferring the zip file from one machine to another?

Comment: I haven't found any definitive source of information but [unofficial ones](https://superuser.com/a/1525985) say Windows 7 supports deflate and deflate64 which the class _does_ support. Just now I created a zipped folder and then opened it with another utility (7-zip) I have which indicates the files in it are all compressed with method "deflate" — so something else is likely the problem.

Comment: I used winRar to zip this time instead of the Windows default and its works.